# Working out the number of solutions......

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How would I go about figuring out the number of solutions in $x^2=-1211 ($mod $2020)$. I wrote out the prime factorisation of $2020$ which is $2^2 \times 5 \times 101 $but I sort of found myself getting very confused afterwards, watching several videos seemed to make that even worse so some step-by-step explanations would really help!

Comment: You need to count the solutions modulo $4$, modulo $5$ and modulo $101$.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Try $x^2\equiv-1211\pmod 4$ first. $4$ is a very small number, and one can go through all possibilities modulo $4$ very quickly.

Comment: Would you do (mod 2) or (mod 4)?

Comment: And if doing (mod 4), I'm unsure of the step to talk after changing the equation to x^2=3 (mod 4).

Comment: Is $3$ a square $\bmod 4$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Use the *Chinese remainder theorem*. Note that
$$1211\equiv \begin{cases}3\mod  4,\\1\mod 5, \\ 100 \mod 101.\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

Your equation is equivalent to$$x^2\equiv  809 \mod 2020$$

Answer (score 0):

Something no one else has mentioned...

Let S = {0, 1, 2, ..., 100}.

One of the steps that you will need to take is to identify all elements x from set S such that $x^2 \equiv -1211 \pmod{101}.$

I know of no straight forward way of mathematically identifying the relevant elements from S.  If I were attacking this problem, I would write a computer program to identify the corresponding elements from S.  Then, as has already been *suggested*, I would educate myself re the **Chinese Remainder Theorem.**